# How to change ttl in windows only for a specific network adapter?

Tags: windows, lan, ttl

I need the correct command to change the TTL on a specific network adapter in a computer
netsh interface ipv4 set global LAN5" defaultcurhoplimit=64
it says to me in the console that the command is not correct